# Writing and execute a SELECT Stored Procedure in PL/SQL

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

I have a problem when i try to write a simple slect stored procedure in PL/SQL (I use a PL/SQL Developer IDE). I'm new in PL/SQL but i have experience in MS SQL where I wrote quite complex stored procedures.

This is my procedure code :

```
    create or replace procedure Overrides_Exceptions_Analysis (data  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS  
BEGIN
  
 OPEN data for
 select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.disbursed_date) AS YEAR,
       CASE
          WHEN t.product_type in('Overdraft', 'Automatic Overdraft') THEN 'Overdraft'
          WHEN t.product_type in('Cash', 'Fast Loan') THEN 'Cash'          
         ELSE t.product_type
       END AS product_type,
       
       sum(t.disbursed_amount_in_lc) as approved_amount_bgn, 
       count(*) as count        
from retail_newly_approved t
where t.disbursed_date > '2020-12-31' and t.product_type not in('Corporate', 'SME_non_Standard', 'SME_Standard')

group by CASE
          WHEN t.product_type in('Overdraft', 'Automatic Overdraft') THEN 'Overdraft'
          WHEN t.product_type in('Cash', 'Fast Loan') THEN 'Cash'          
          ELSE t.product_type
         END,         
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.disbursed_date);
 
DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(data);

end Overrides_Exceptions_Analysis;
```

The procedure compile successfully, but when i tried to execute it in this way :

```
    begin   
        variable mycursor refcursor;  
        overrides_exceptions_analysis(:mycursor);    
    end ;
```

I receive error message : ORA-06550: line 3, column 14: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "MYCURSOR" when expecting one of the following : :=.)@%;

I try to move the parameter from  intut part to the body of the procedure like this :

```
create or replace procedure Overrides_Exceptions_Analysis 
IS   
  data   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
```

In this case, when i execute the procedure like that:

```
 begin 
  overrides_exceptions_analysis; 
 end ;
```

I did't receive the previous error message and the procedure is executed successfully, but without returning the expected data set?

Comment: You don't need a colon when referencing PL/SQL variables.

Comment: @mustaccio I tried it in both variant and I still get an error. Can you be more specific ?